# Publish in facebook group using facebook graph api

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have user token and app token and I want to post on my group. I give it a permission to publish on the group.

```
from facebook import GraphAPI
graph = GraphAPI(access_token='my_access_token')
message = '''
the message
'''
groups = graph.get_object("me/groups")

graph.put_object('my_group_id', "feed", message=message)
```

I use this code. but I get a problem

```
raise GraphAPIError(result)
facebook.GraphAPIError: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \
          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \
          sufficient administrative permission
```

Do I need to use the app token or what is the problem?

Comment: Did you install the app in the group?

Comment: Yes i install it to the group

Comment: Debug the actual access token used, to verify it really contains the necessary permission.

Comment: @Shatha how did you installed the app to the group? what did you do to make it shows in the list to be installed?